# how to store Date in some variable in c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include </usr/local/include/mysql++/mysql++.h>
#include "/usr/local/include/mysql++/cmdline.h"
#include </usr/include/mysql/mysql_version.h>
int main(){
           if(conn1.connect(db1, server, username, pass))
            {

             mysqlpp::Query query = conn1.query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE FIND_IN_SET('"+strzipcode+"',`Zipcodes`);");
                  if (mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult res1 =query.store())
                     {
                       cout << "We have:"<<endl;
                        for (size_t i= 0; i < res1.num_rows();i++)
                          {
                            cout<<res1[i][0]<<endl;
                          }
                     }
           return 0;
           }
```

// here res1[i][0] gives me Date which is stored in my database (2014-01-10).
I want to store this date in some variable and print for further processing .Because in my next query i need to pass this date as variable .
I tried this to convert in double or int like :

```
int dateStart =atoi(res1[i][1]);
cout << "DateStart :"<<dateStart << endl;
```

But this is giving me output 2014 only not 2014-01-10.
As I am new to c++ i need your help .Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why not simply use a `string`?

Comment: can you explain how ?? i tried with string but it was giving me an error

Comment: What's the type of `res1[i][1]`?

Comment: its date return from database .so i guess it has datatype string

Comment: Given it can pass to `atoi()`, you should be able to use `string` to store it directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you get the Date as a string `2014-01-10` and `atoi()` cuts it at the "-"-sign.

```
std::string date;
res1[i][1].to_string(date);
int  year = atoi(date.substr(0,4));
int  month = atoi(date.substr(5,2));
int  day = atoi(date.substr(8,2));
```

and of course `#include <string>`
I think there are more elegant solutions with date format as well.

Update: Ok, if it is sufficient to handle your date in string and you are not interested in the components, you need to tell us, which datatype res1 is.

Comment: .it is not working for me .res1[i][1] has datatype string when it is return from datbase

Comment: Ok, then you need a conversion from `mysqlpp::String` to `std::string`. You can try `std::string date; res1[i][1].toString(date);` See: http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/doc/html/refman/classmysqlpp_1_1String.html

Comment: std::string date; res1[i][1].to_string(date);

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the lib you're using, from what I can see I guess that

```
res[][]
```

is a string array, so you can split your string by the char '-' and store your values into three separate variables (or better a structure, or whatever you want).

However, I'm sure that there are better ways to handle this kind of data, I suggest you to check documentation to see if there's a way to obtain a double or a long from query.

Comment: I don't know how to split string and store values in 2 separate variable .can you tell me how to do that ?

Comment: @Marik suggested you easy solution if you know that you always get the date in format YYYY-MM-DD, so accept and follow his solution. If this is not true you probably need to build your own function to split.